# Mysql: How to configure mysql proxy for fail over handling

Tags: mysql, configuration, proxy

We have a master - slave replication with single master and single slave.
Shall we use mysql proxy to handle failover from master to salve ?

If YES, please explain how this should be configured.
I could not able to find better documentation on this. moreover I am new to this proxy.

Regards,
Uday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Proxy is a simple program that sits between your client and MySQL server(s) that can monitor, analyze or transform their communication. Its flexibility allows for unlimited uses; common ones include: load balancing; failover; query analysis; query filtering and modification; and many more.

Two fairly common usage scenarios for MySQL Proxy are:

1) load balancing across MySQL slaves

2) splitting reads and writes so that reads go to the slave DB
    servers and writes go to the master DB server

Of course, you don't need MySQL Proxy to accomplish these goals. For slave load balancing, you can use a regular load balancer in front of your slaves. For read-write splitting, you can have your application use different DB servers for reads and writes....but that may require significant changes to your application.

If you want to make things faster in terms of read performance by sending reads to a pool of slave DB servers, while still sending writes to a master DB, AND do all this without modifying your application, then MySQL Proxy might be just the ticket for you.

For more information refer this :
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/mysql-proxy-howto.html

Simple configuration of MySQL proxy is mentioned below:

> ```
>  D:\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-0.8.1-win32-x86\bin>mysql-proxy.exe --proxy-backend-addresses=<serverIP>:3306 --proxy-address=<proxyIP>:4040 --admin-username=ro
>     ot --admin-password=root --admin-lua-script=<LUA acript> --proxy-lua-script=<same as mentioned in --admin-lua-script>
> ```

**This config setup applies for MySQL-proxy v0.8.1**

Comment: Thanq mahi... Where are you mentioning the two server IPs here...?

Comment: You just provide multiple --proxy-backend-addresses. See [MySQL Manual - Using MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-proxy-using.html)